# Recover the value of an object if the key match

Tags: javascript

I would like to recover the value of a key in an object if the key matches with the condition

here is the condition :

```
var lang = 'EN'
```

here is the condition :

```
var translate : {EN: "name_EN", FR: "name_FR", NL: "name_NL"}
```

if the key corresponds to the variable lang I would like to recover the corresponding value.

here -> "name_EN"

Comment: `translate[lang]` will be enough, you need to use `[]` access dynamic property

Comment: @Code Maniac thanks a lot !